# Settings for matching words box hightlight and odd green/blue bar to the right

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, phpstorm, webstorm

I have troubles finding settings for these two things, as I just want them removed.

I'm using WebStorm 2017.3 EAP, but afaik, this *would* be the same in the other IntelliJ products.

Both issues are on both themes, however the default theme, be bounding box is not as apparent.

1. The white bounding box that appears on matching words (around `services` in the screenshot. I just want it dimmed a bit.
   This looks like this is only Material UI, but could be related settings.
2. Far right green border. It's there in some files not in others, and I can't figure out *what* it actually represents. Some times it's blue. I just want it removed.
   Note: This is not the no the hard wrap guide line, as I removed that already.

I've really tried looking through all settings, but I think I might not be using the correct terminology.

Thank you on beforehand, this is driving me nuts.

Edit: Updated images and with default theme + material theme eap.

**Edit: Solved problem number 1. It's `Editor -> Color Scheme -> General -> Code -> Identifier under caret**

[image: Darcula default theme]
[image: Material theme EAP]

Comment: 1) Use StackOverflow's functionality for images 2) Make screenshot using bundled theme, preferably Default -- not everyone is using custom Material theme. This is to identify the styling elements (if they are similar in that theme as well). Once they are known it can easily be changed. But in general in could be `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Color Scheme |  General | Search Results`. **P.S.** I'm not 100% sure if Material theme is bundled with 2017.3 (quite possibly it is) ... but in 2017.2 and earlier it's a 3rd party plugin that needs to be installed separately.

Comment: Thank you @LazyOne - I've updated the post now to be more fulfilling. I found first setting was in `Code -> Identifier under caret`
Now just the last green bar.

Comment: Thin vertical green bar on the right side? It looks similar to the one on Darcula screenshot on the left side .. which is VCS status for those lines (added lines).

Comment: @LazyOne no it's not that one. The green line/bar is on both screenshots to the right. Just around where the inspection stuff is.

Comment: Disable VCS integration for this project (+ maybe restart IDE) and see if it will disappear.

Comment: Disabling the VCS integration did indeed remove that bar. Looking through the color scheme settings again, I still only find settings for the gutter bar to the right. Getting closer though. Edit: After committing the files to git, it got removed. So I guess it's the same purpose as left gutter, but not configurable perhaps.

Comment: Look under `Color Scheme | Diff & Merge` -- you cannot remove them from the scroolbar completely .. but you can make them less noticeable. At the same time -- this setting *should* turn off all VCS markings — `Settings/Preferences | Editor | General --> Highlight modified lines in gutter`